# Google Web Toolkit like application in Django

Tags: python, django, gwt

I'm trying to develop an application that would be perfect for GWT, however I am using this app as a learning example for Django. Is there some precedence for this type of application in Django?

Answer (score 7):

[Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) is sort of like GWT which is written with Python. From there you can make it work with your django code.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of people have done this by writing their UI in GWT and having it issue ajax calls back to their python backend. There are basically two ways to go about it. First, you can simply use JSON to communicate between the frontend and the backend. That's the approach you will find here (http://palantar.blogspot.com/2006/06/agad-tutorial-ish-sort-of-post.html). Second, some people want to use GWT's RPC system to talk to python backends. This is a little more involved, but some people have created tools (for example, http://code.google.com/p/python-gwt-rpc/).

To be honest, most successful projects just use JSON to communicate between GWT and the python server. GWT's RPC is pretty advanced in that it is able to serialize arbitrary java object graphs to and from the client. It's a tricky problem to get right and I'm pretty doubtful that any of the python tools have it right.